# Orika - map Page<T> to Page<TDto>

Tags: java, spring, orika

I have a problem in mapping Page object to Page object.
I have the following Mapper class:

```
package com.agileplayers.agilemanager.core.mapper;

import com.agileplayers.agilemanager.core.domain.Account;
import com.agileplayers.agilemanager.core.domain.Entry;
import com.agileplayers.agilemanager.core.dto.AccountDto;
import com.agileplayers.agilemanager.core.dto.EntryDto;
import ma.glasnost.orika.MapperFacade;
import ma.glasnost.orika.MapperFactory;
import ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory;
import ma.glasnost.orika.metadata.TypeBuilder;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class Mapper {
    final static MapperFactory MAPPER_FACTORY = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();

    public MapperFacade getMapperFacade(){
        registerMappers();
        return MAPPER_FACTORY.getMapperFacade();
    }

    private void registerMappers(){
        MAPPER_FACTORY.classMap(Entry.class, EntryDto.class)
                .byDefault()
                .register();

        MAPPER_FACTORY.classMap(Account.class, AccountDto.class)
                .byDefault()
                .register();
        MAPPER_FACTORY.classMap(
                new TypeBuilder<PageImpl<Entry>>() {}.build(),
                new TypeBuilder<PageImpl<EntryDto>>() {}.build())
                .byDefault()
                .register();

    }
}
```

which is used here:

```
@Autowired
    private EntryRepository entryRepository;

    private void start() {
        Mapper mapper = new Mapper();
        Page<Entry> entryPage = entryRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(0, 2));

        Type<Page<Entry>> pageEntryType = new TypeBuilder<Page<Entry>>() {
        }.build();
        Type<Page<EntryDto>> pageEntryDtoType = new TypeBuilder<Page<EntryDto>>() {
        }.build();

        Page<EntryDto> entryDtoPage = mapper.getMapperFacade().map(entryPage, pageEntryType, pageEntryDtoType);
```

unfortunately, I am receiving the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" ma.glasnost.orika.MappingException: While attempting the following mapping:
sourceClass = class org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl
sourceType = org.springframework.data.domain.Page<Entry>
destinationType = org.springframework.data.domain.Page<EntryDto>
resolvedStrategy = InstantiateAndUseCustomMapperStrategy<PageImpl<Entry>, PageImpl<EntryDto>> {customMapper: GeneratedMapper<PageImpl<Entry>, PageImpl<EntryDto>> {usedConverters: [], usedMappers: [], usedMapperFacades: [DefaultBoundMapperFacade<Sort, Sort>], usedTypes: [Object] }, unenhancer: ma.glasnost.orika.unenhance.BaseUnenhancer@4b5aa48b, objectFactory: ma.glasnost.orika.generated.PageImpl_PageImpl_ObjectFactory59678627946495970211838179$3@2dd2ff87}
Error occurred: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
-----begin dump of current state-----------------------------
Registered object factories: 3 (approximate size: 9,541.1 kB)
  [AccountDto] : {Account=DefaultConstructorObjectFactory<AccountDto>}
  [PageImpl<EntryDto>] : {PageImpl<Entry>=ma.glasnost.orika.generated.PageImpl_PageImpl_ObjectFactory59678627946495970211838179$3@2dd2ff87}
  [EntryDto] : {Entry=DefaultConstructorObjectFactory<EntryDto>}
-------------------------------------------------------------
Registered mappers: 3 (approximate size: 9,794.2 kB)
  [0] : GeneratedMapper<PageImpl<Entry>, PageImpl<EntryDto>> {usedConverters: [], usedMappers: [], usedMapperFacades: [DefaultBoundMapperFacade<Sort, Sort>], usedTypes: [Object] }
  [1] : GeneratedMapper<Entry, EntryDto> {usedConverters: [builtin:CloneableConverter(Copy by cloning:Date, Calendar, XMLGregorianCalendar)], usedMappers: [], usedMapperFacades: [DefaultBoundMapperFacade<Account, AccountDto>], usedTypes: [Date] }
  [2] : GeneratedMapper<Account, AccountDto> {usedConverters: [builtin:CloneableConverter(Copy by cloning:Date, Calendar, XMLGregorianCalendar)], usedMappers: [], usedMapperFacades: [], usedTypes: [Date, Entry, EntryDto] }
-------------------------------------------------------------
Registered concrete types: 6 (approximate size: 346.9 kB)
  [interface java.util.Collection] : ArrayList<Object>
  [interface java.util.Map] : LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>
  [interface java.util.Map$Entry] : MapEntry<Object, Object>
  [Page<Entry>] : PageImpl<EntryDto>
  [interface java.util.List] : ArrayList<Object>
  [interface java.util.Set] : LinkedHashSet<Object>
-------------------------------------------------------------
Resolved strategies: 4 (approximate size: 9,794.6 kB)
{source: PageImpl, dest: Page<EntryDto>, in-place:false}: InstantiateAndUseCustomMapperStrategy<PageImpl<Entry>, PageImpl<EntryDto>> {customMapper: GeneratedMapper<PageImpl<Entry>, PageImpl<EntryDto>> {usedConverters: [], usedMappers: [], usedMapperFacades: [DefaultBoundMapperFacade<Sort, Sort>], usedTypes: [Object] }, unenhancer: ma.glasnost.orika.unenhance.BaseUnenhancer@4b5aa48b, objectFactory: ma.glasnost.orika.generated.PageImpl_PageImpl_ObjectFactory59678627946495970211838179$3@2dd2ff87}
{source: Account, dest: AccountDto, in-place:false}: InstantiateAndUseCustomMapperStrategy<Account, AccountDto> {customMapper: GeneratedMapper<Account, AccountDto> {usedConverters: [builtin:CloneableConverter(Copy by cloning:Date, Calendar, XMLGregorianCalendar)], usedMappers: [], usedMapperFacades: [], usedTypes: [Date, Entry, EntryDto] }, unenhancer: ma.glasnost.orika.unenhance.BaseUnenhancer@4b5aa48b, objectFactory: DefaultConstructorObjectFactory<AccountDto>}
{source: Entry, dest: Object, in-place:false}: InstantiateAndUseCustomMapperStrategy<Entry, EntryDto> {customMapper: GeneratedMapper<Entry, EntryDto> {usedConverters: [builtin:CloneableConverter(Copy by cloning:Date, Calendar, XMLGregorianCalendar)], usedMappers: [], usedMapperFacades: [DefaultBoundMapperFacade<Account, AccountDto>], usedTypes: [Date] }, unenhancer: ma.glasnost.orika.unenhance.BaseUnenhancer@4b5aa48b, objectFactory: DefaultConstructorObjectFactory<EntryDto>}
{source: Entry, dest: EntryDto, in-place:false}: InstantiateAndUseCustomMapperStrategy<Entry, EntryDto> {customMapper: GeneratedMapper<Entry, EntryDto> {usedConverters: [builtin:CloneableConverter(Copy by cloning:Date, Calendar, XMLGregorianCalendar)], usedMappers: [], usedMapperFacades: [DefaultBoundMapperFacade<Account, AccountDto>], usedTypes: [Date] }, unenhancer: ma.glasnost.orika.unenhance.BaseUnenhancer@4b5aa48b, objectFactory: DefaultConstructorObjectFactory<EntryDto>}
-------------------------------------------------------------
Unenhance strategy: ma.glasnost.orika.unenhance.BaseUnenhancer@4b5aa48b
-----end dump of current state-------------------------------
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.ExceptionUtility.newMappingException(ExceptionUtility.java:55)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.MapperFacadeImpl.map(MapperFacadeImpl.java:280)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.MapperFacadeImpl.map(MapperFacadeImpl.java:243)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.MapperFacadeImpl.map(MapperFacadeImpl.java:133)
    at com.agileplayers.agilemanager.AgileManagerApplication.start(AgileManagerApplication.java:49)
    at com.agileplayers.agilemanager.AgileManagerApplication.main(AgileManagerApplication.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.clear(Collections.java:1074)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.generated.Orika_PageImpl_PageImpl_Mapper5970055563717$0.mapAtoB(Orika_PageImpl_PageImpl_Mapper5970055563717$0.java)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.mapping.strategy.UseCustomMapperStrategy.map(UseCustomMapperStrategy.java:67)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.MapperFacadeImpl.map(MapperFacadeImpl.java:266)
    ... 9 more
```

There is no problem in mapping Entry to EntryDto or List to List. I assume the problem might be with parameterless constructor in PageImpl class but it is only my suspicion.
Please advise, what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why so complex? The `Page` has a `map` method (if you use spring data common 1.10 or newer). You only need to pass the function to do the mapping and be done with it, you are making it to complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Spring Data Commons 1.10 or newer the `Page` object has a `map` method. Just use that to your advantage.

For the next sample I assume you are actually using that.

```
private void start() {
    final Mapper mapper = new Mapper();
    Page<Entry> entryPage = entryRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(0, 2));
    Page<EntryDto> entryDtoPage = entryPage.map(
        new Converter<Entry, EntryDto>() {
            public EntryDto convert(Entry source) {
                mapper.getMapperFacade().map(source, EntryDto);
            }
    });
```

No need to provide any other code trying to map/hack/reconstruct the actual Page. When on JDK8 you can probably replace it with a nice lamda making the code even smaller.

Comment: I am new in Java comming from .NET world. Thank you! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The `Page` object does have a `.map()` method, so this would be as easy as:

```
  Page<SomeEntity> daoPage = service.getEntities();
  Page<SomeDto> dtoPage = daoPage.map(it -> mapper.map(it, SomeDto.class));
```